# Join tables with with a condition and then aggregate columns

Tags: laravel

Given I have a simple join between two tables user and filled forms, filled forms has columns: value, sales and income.

Sales and income are boolean columns if any of them are set to true then I know which value are sales and which are income.

```
User::where('id', $id)
         ->leftJoin("filled_forms", function($join){

           $join->on("user.form_id", "filled_forms.id")
                ->where("filled_forms.sales", true)
                ->where("filled_forms.income", true);
          })->get();
```

> Now all the fields that sales are set to true I want to
>   `count(filled_forms.value) as number_of_sales` and all the incomes
>   that are set to true I want to do `sum(filled_forms.value) as income`

I know that I could do something with `DB::Raw` maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SQL View for such requirements as it will provide you with a table with real time updated information. 
http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-views.htm

Then you can follow standard laravel where condition to fetch data from the view.

Comment: right, its just that I didnt tag mysql in this case because I want it in laravel way.

Comment: You only need to run the SQL command once to create the view and then do all the other operations on this view using laravel eloquent.